# can i use all CPUs and Cores to process images?

Tags: python

i'm new on coding with python

so i have a project to make face recognition, i have 20 folders and each folder contains 4 images. but when i run my code, the encoding process took a lot of time.

so this is my code:

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os 
import glob

path = './dataset'
folders = [f for f in glob.glob(path + '**/*', recursive=True)]

known_face_encodings = []
known_face_names = []

for f in folders:
    names = f.split('/')[2]
    print('encoding file : {}'.format(names))
    for images_f in glob.glob(f + '**/*.jpg'):

        images = face_recognition.load_image_file(images_f)
        location = face_recognition.face_locations(images)
        images_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(images, known_face_locations = location)[0]
        known_face_encodings.append(images_encoding)
        known_face_names.append(names)
```

is there anything that i can do to make the encode process faster? and how? thanks in advance

Comment: [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: I think you've to clarify the bound of your program, IO or CPU calculation.

If IO is the bound, you can preload all the files first or batch read.
If CPU calculation, it's better to improve the process of face_recognition.face_encodings

Comment: Can you check your CPU usage to make sure it is the problem? And how long roughly is each image taking? Maybe that's what normally happens, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use this to split your processing into different threads:

```
import threading

def face_recognition_function( f ) :
    names = f.split('/')[2]
    print('encoding file : {}'.format(names))
    for images_f in glob.glob(f + '**/*.jpg'):

        images = face_recognition.load_image_file(images_f)
        location = face_recognition.face_locations(images)
        images_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(images, known_face_locations = location)[0]
        known_face_encodings.append(images_encoding)
        known_face_names.append(names)

threads = []
for f in folders:
    t = threading.Thread(target=face_recognition_function, args=(f,))
    t.start()
    threads.append( t )

# threads work now on your images

for t in threads :
    t.join()  # wait for the completion
```

The current version of code starts a new thread for every folder. If this somehow makes your computer to run out of memory or leads to unpredicted results, you may want to create less parallel threads. However, with 20 folders, I don't think anything wrong could happen here.